# Honeywell Programmable Light Switch Timer - different settings for outlet vs. light fixture?

Tags: wiring, timer

We have a Honeywell Programmable Light Switch Timer (https://www.honeywellhome.com/us/en/products/energy/light-switch-timers/7-day-solar-programmable-light-switch-timer-white-rpls740b1008-u/) that controls both an outlet and light fixture on the exterior of our home. We would like to set the timer so that the light fixture turns on at dusk and off at dawn, while the Nest Camera plugged into the outlet runs constantly.

Thus far, I've been unable to figure out how to do this. Does anyone know if this is even possible? I've read through the manual and have watched a handful of videos, but can't find anything on the subject.

One last item to share: our house is not a new build. The switch timer was installed when we moved in, and the outdoor light was on a schedule set by the switch timer. When I installed our Next Cam and used the associated outlet, the Nest Cam had power even when the light switch was off. Or at least that's how I remember it. Either way, the setup appeared to work as desired (refer back to first paragraph) before the switch got reset and I had to reprogram it from factory settings. So, it seems like this was working just fine before and I just don't know how to program my switch. Or, I'm totally misremembering/wasn't paying attention to how it was working before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you upload pictures showing all the wires attached to the timer and all the wires attached to the receptacle?